# "Public documented API" broken in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I'm running Sonar 5.0 with the Java 2.8 plugin. It generates a percentage value for public documented API, which is extremely low.

This is caused by having entity classes like the following being marked as 0% being documented:

```
public class SomeEntity {
  /** Some Javadoc */
  private String someField;
  public String getSomeField() { return someField; }
  public void setSomeField(String someField) { this.someField = someField; }
}
```

Based on https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:UndocumentedApi?layout=false I'd argue that getters and setters should be ignored. Is there some magic trick to convince sonarqube to no longer warn about these?

Answer (score 2):

The only element that is public in your example (the `SomeEntity` class) is not documented at all, so that might explain why your "Public documented API" measure is very low.

Comment: But to quote https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:UndocumentedApi?layout=false

The following public methods and constructors are not taken into account by this rule: Getters and setters, Methods with @Override annotationm, Empty constructors, Static constants.

Even with a class comment it results in a very low measure.

Are getters/setters counted as "public API" nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

There is one comment missing for the class

```
/** COMMENT YOUR CLASS **/    
public class SomeEntity {
  /** Some Javadoc */
  private String someField;
  public String getSomeField() { return someField; }
  public void setSomeField(String someField) { this.someField = someField; }
}
```